# In windows phone 8.1 i need to select text inside textbox and on selection i need to get popUP

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, windows-phone-8.1

Using Textbox I need to search data and after getting list I need to add that selected item to text box and after selection text need to replace in same  textbox, now I need to select that text inside Textbox and on selection I need to get message popup

This is my textbox:

```
<TextBlock Text="Participants*" FontSize="18" Margin="20,20,20,5"/>
<TextBox x:Name="TxtParticipants" Margin="20,5,20,0" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" SelectionChanged="TxtParticipants_SelectionChanged" >
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TextChanged">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SearchInboxCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TxtParticipants, Path=Text}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

This is my listview

```
<ListView Grid.Row="4" x:Name="ParticipantsList" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResult}" Margin="20,0,20,5" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemClick="ParticipantsList_ItemClick" >
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick" >
            <core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="TxtParticipants"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtDesignation" Text="{Binding Designation}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtCompany" Margin="2,0,0,0">
                        <Run>,</Run>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Company}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Same process is happening in windows phone on composing To messages.

Comment: I need to select that text inside text box and on selection I need to get Message PopUp

Comment: Pls show us your code you have tried so far.

Comment: marcel I am new to this website how can I add data in comment I dont Know

Comment: put code into \`\` in comments or type 4 white spaces (no tab!) before a line of code in questions and answers.

Comment: If you have issues with editing please refer to this webpage: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: <TextBlock Text="Participants*"
FontSize="18"
 Margin="20,20,20,5"/>
<TextBox x:Name="TxtParticipants"  
 Margin="20,5,20,0"
  Text=""
TextWrapping="Wrap" SelectionChanged="TxtParticipants_SelectionChanged"  >

 <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TextChanged">
<core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SearchInboxCommand}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TxtParticipants, Path=Text}"/>
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>

Comment: after searching I am showing that in list view

Comment: <ListView Grid.Row="4" x:Name="ParticipantsList" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResult}"  
                          Margin="20,0,20,5"    
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  SelectionMode="Single" ItemClick="ParticipantsList_ItemClick"
                   >
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick" >
                    <core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="TxtParticipants"></core:CallMethodAction>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

Comment: <ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition/>
<RowDefinition/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtDesignation" Text="{Binding Designation}">
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock x:Name="txtCompany"  Margin="2,0,0,0">
<Run>,</Run>
<Run Text="{Binding Company}"></Run>
</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>  
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>

Comment: I have edited your post to include the code you have posted as comments. You can always [edit] your own post. Please visit the [help] to learn how the functionalities of this site works. Please delete your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Its  quite  simple...

please add  Auto  complete  control   and  POPUP  control  to  XAMl..
Aurocomplete text boix  is  a  customized  control
please  check  this  link
[AUTOCOMPLETE TEXT BOX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26535/WPF-Autocomplete-Textbox-Control)
you  can  add  this  text box  to  your  toolkit 
by downloading  WPF  toolkit [WPF TOOLKIT](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535)

to  use  this  add  the  following  namespace in xaml

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFAutoCompleteTextbox"
```

xaml  code  for AUTOCOMPLETE TEXTBOX

```
<local:AutoCompleteTextBox Height="23" Width="240" x:Name="textBox1" 
DelayTime="500" Threshold="2"/>
```

code  behind  to add  items  to this  textbox

```
   textBox1.AddItem(new AutoCompleteEntry
("Toyota Camry", "Toyota Camry", "camry", "car", "sedan"));
 textBox1.AddItem(new AutoCompleteEntry
("Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corolla", "corolla", "car", "compact"));
textBox1.AddItem(new AutoCompleteEntry
("Toyota Tundra", "Toyota Tundra", "tundra", "truck"));
// null matching string will default with just the name
textBox1.AddItem(new AutoCompleteEntry("Chevy Impala", null));
textBox1.AddItem(new AutoCompleteEntry
("Chevy Tahoe", "Chevy Tahoe", "tahoe", "truck", "SUV"));
textBox1.AddItem(new AutoCompleteEntry
("Chevrolet Malibu", "Chevrolet Malibu", "malibu", "car", "sedan"));
```

Xaml  code for adding  popup

```
 <Popup Name="popupDisplay" Margin="45,228,55,223" Visibility="Visible"  >
 </Popup >
```

to display  the  popup..
use  this  code  in .CS file

```
popup.isopen=true;
```

to  collapse(close) the  popup ,

```
popup.isopen=false
```

Add SELECTION CHANGED AND TEXTCHANGED  event  handler  to  Auto complete control..  when  that event  completes , bring  the  popup  control  to  front..
  Accept this  as  answer by  clickling  Tick  Mark..please  reply  for  further  info..